# how to connect "dual mode HDMI" to get 60Hz 4K?

Tags: hdmi

I bought Gigabyte GeForce GTX 750Ti graphics card, that says prominently on the box "4k at 60Hz through dual HDMI".

OK, so I tried to connect this by 2 HDMI cables, to 2 HDMI inputs on my 4K TV, and what I get is two displays, of course, one on each input.  I don't get ONE display at 60Hz.

Exactly how to connect this "4K 60Hz through dual HDMI" to a TV??

I found that Gigabyte has nonexistent customer support, no phone numbers I can reach, and no manual for this thing.  Maybe that is why they make claims that may not be true.  I don't know.

But if there is a way to get this to work, as it says on the box, can someone please explain it to me.

Comment: You're in the chicken and the egg scenario - 4k@60Hz really needs HDMI 2.0.  As a stopgap, this "HDMI Dual" solution is being used by some, but you need a monitor/display/tv that supports it.

Comment: Fine.  What do you mean by "tv that supports it", can you elaborate it?

Comment: As in the TV or monitor has to have been specially designed to use it, like the [Asus PQ321Q](http://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/4K-Monitor-Requirements-and-Usage-492/).  Since you've got a Kepler based card, you might be able to get [4k@60hz with the driver trick that Nvidia's doing](http://www.anandtech.com/show/8191/nvidia-kepler-cards-get-hdmi-4k60hz-support-kind-of), if your TV supports 4:2:0 4K

Comment: Well, believe it or not, I got 60Hz on _one_ HDMI cable, 4K.  The only problem is that black text, on some colors background, in html, is blurry.  Like on red, is blurry.  On green it is not.  And in pictures, black lines on red background are sharp.  Do you know by chance what's up with black on red HTML that it does not work?

Comment: What TV/monitor are you using?

Comment: I think text clarity on TVs (used as PC monitors) has to do with what chroma is supported by the TV and graphics card.  It sounds like 4:4:4 is ideal, but not always supported.

Comment: 4:4:4 means that every single pixel has full color information. 4:2:0 means that the color information is essentially halved in both horizontal and vertical - you've got full 4k information for the brightness of each pixel, but each grouping of 4 pixels share the same color information. Couple this with ClearType, which tries to use sub-pixel hinting (using the various color components of your pixels cleverly to make your text appear sharper) and you will definitely end up with blurry, screwy looking text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First at all your graphic card won't support 4k@60hz with 1 HDMI cable.

The meaning of 4k@60hz you mentioned is you using 2 monitor connected to the graphic card with 2 HDMI cable, meaning each monitor have 1920x1080@60hz. Only NVidia series **900 and higher** will give you 4k@60hz with single cable.

Last, you can't give 1 monitor to display input from 2 HDMI cable at once!